# AutoSuggestBox redoing the search after keyboard input

Tags: c#, uwp

I've worked on WinForms and WPF before, but this is my first time working in UWP.

I'm trying to create a textbox thas search in a item list and it does return the search and list items, but when you try yo navigate through them with the keyboard, the first result is searched again efectively killing the rest of the search.

this is the XAML Code for the AutoSuggestBox:

```
<AutoSuggestBox
PlaceholderText="Buscar" QueryIcon="Find" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind SearchResult}" TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen" QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
/>
```

And this is the C# Code behind:

```cs
        private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                SearchResult = indexedTree.FindAll(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(sender.Text.ToLower()));

                if (SearchResult.Count < 0)
                    SearchResult.Clear();
                sender.ItemsSource = SearchResult;
            }
        }

        private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.SelectedItem is ExplorerItem item)
                sender.Text = item.Name;
        }

        private void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
        {
            if(args.ChosenSuggestion != null && args.ChosenSuggestion is ExplorerItem item)
            {
                sender.Text = item.Name;
                sender.ItemsSource = null;
            }
        }
```

my guess is that somehow the selection chosen event is also triggering the text changed event as a user input, but i'm not sure, i've looked the XAML Control Gallery Code and in that app works fine and code is really similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my guess is that somehow the selection chosen event is also triggering the text changed event as a user input

For my testing, [`SuggestionChosen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.suggestionchosen) event will not cause [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.textchanged) invoked with `UserInput` reason. Even we set `sender.Text = item.Name`. If we set sender.Text value, it will invoke `TextChanged`, but the args.Reason is `SuggestionChosen`. We have not need to pass the select item to the  `AutoSuggestBox` text property, and `AutoSuggestBox` will automatically get the select value.

Comment: Not setting the sender.Text on SuggestionChosen does work, but as ExplorerItem is a somewhat complex class, when navigating its listing as Program.ExplorerItem.

Correct me, but TextMemberPath="Name" should do the job, but it is not